# How to change the Function value to the one from the table (Gamma Distribution) in C++?

Tags: c++, statistics, probability, gamma-distribution

I have task to make a program using C++ to calculate a probability using a Gamma distribution. If i already found the Function value, how to change it to become the one from the Gamma Distribution table? I don't know the formulas.

For example Fg(8;8), in the table is 0.5470. And Fg(4;8) in the table is 0.0511.

[Standard Gamma Cumulative Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEgBX.jpg)

Comment: Would [std::gamma_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/gamma_distribution) be helpful?

Comment: You should know that the CDF (cumulative distribution function) of a statistical distribution is just the integral of it from 0, This applies to any of the distribution functions. That's why the numbers differ. Vincent's answer details ways to compute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing such a function in "pure" C++ from scratch is not that easy as AFAIK C++ standard lib ([Common mathematical functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math) & [Mathematical special functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_math)) does not support the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) which is required to compute [Gamma distribution cumulative function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math).

Instead I would recommend to use the [Boost library's implementation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/dists/gamma_dist.html)

```
// -*- compile-command: "g++ gamma.cpp; ./a.out"; -*-
//
#include <boost/math/distributions/gamma.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::math;

int main()
{
  gamma_distribution<> dist(8.,1);

  std::cout << "\n" << cdf(dist,8);
  std::cout << "\n" << cdf(dist,4);
}
```

prints:

```
0.547039
0.0511336
```

as expected

Comment: can i make and use an array table and just called it?

Comment: If you have no contraint (like performance one), the simplest option IMHO is to call the cdf() function when you need values.

Comment: I'm still confused sir. Can I use such as erf, erfc, tgamma? In Cumulative Normal Distribution Function, i can simply use it. Is there any example from cdf() function?

Comment: @SatriaAdi Yes. I would recommend first to be sure to have understood the mathematical definition of [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) and then you can read the boost manual: [Statistical Distributions and Functions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/math/doc/html/dist.html). I have to leave office... goot luck.